# How do I read a tab delimited file to find the line which has a known value?

Tags: vb.net

I have a tab delimited file which has data like this...

```
022j<TAB>10.375
023j<TAB>12.365
024j<TAB>15.230
```

NOTE: this will not let me post as it is... each 02xj is a different line in the text file. It

EG: 023j is input into a textbox.

Need to find the value associated with the input; 12.365 in this case.

There are a few different files (some are encoded 012j, 012#, 012$ etc. which will correspond to different data.)

My head is exploding trying to find a way to take what I have in the textbox then read through and find the data I need.

I know this is easy, please nudge me in the right direction.

Comment: please fix your title to something relevant to the problem/question - it will likely save you some DVs.  See [Ask]

Comment: Open each file, read them line by line until one starts with the text in your textbox, return the value after the tab.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your nudge. You should be able to use something like this:

```
Dim searchValue As Decimal = 023j 'or someTextBox.Text whatever
Dim searchField As Int32 = 0
Dim returnField As Int32 = 1
Dim returnValue As String = ""
Dim returnLineNumber as Int32 = 0

Using fileReader As New FileIO.TextFieldParser(YourFileNameWithPathAsString)
    fileReader.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
    fileReader.SetDelimiters(vbTab)
    While Not fileReader.EndOfData
        Dim currentLine As String() = fileReader.ReadFields()
        If currentLine(searchField) = searchValue Then
            returnValue = currentLine(returnField)
            returnLineNumber = fileReader.LineNumber
            Exit While
        End If
    End While
End Using

Return returnValue 'or Return returnLineNumber if that is what you need
```

You should be able to make it a function and if no result is returned then check your next file.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out... so this is what I ended up doing.

First set up the streamreader

```
'set reader to read the file
        Dim reader As New System.IO.StreamReader(filetoread)
```

Then loop through the file line by line, use contains to find the string to match. Do whatever trimming/extracting and you're there.

```
Do While reader.Peek() >= 0

        line = reader.ReadLine

        If line.Contains(TB_Input.Text) Then
            s = Replace(line, TB_Input.Text, "")
            s = Replace(s, vbTab, "")
            TB_Length.Text = s
        End If
    Loop
```

I was leaking brain juice on this. Until someone basically said "just do it"... thanks I needed that.
 I know there are things like variables I don't explain... I figured anyone looking will know, if that's a bad assumption let me know.

Thanks again